# Same date in different format returning different values

Tags: javascript, date

Same date in different format returning different values. Hence comparison is not matching.

Example below:

```js
alert(new Date(Date.parse('2015-02-03')));

alert(new Date(Date.parse('02/03/2015')));
```

or

```js
alert(new Date('2015-02-03').setHours(0,0,0,0));

alert(new Date('02/03/2015').setHours(0,0,0,0));
```

I am looking for a way to match both exactly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hmm interesting:  `new Date(Date.parse('2015-02-03'))` returns `Tue Feb 03 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100`. Why 01:00 ?

Comment: Probably related to the timezone?, sigh, javascript and dates.  Funny quote on mozilla: "A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date (other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected)."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [ISO 8601 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) `YYYY-MM-DD` format without a timezone given, UTC is assumed. With a non-ISO format like `YYYY/MM/DD` or `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`, the result is implementation (e.g., browser) specific.